# "Set as Default" or "Set as Default Communication"

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 audio settings I have options for speaker as well as mic (internal and external devices) to  "Set as Default"  or  "Set as Default Communications Device"
What is the difference ??

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of "Title" used to tell which audio will be played by which audio device:

**"Default Communications Device"** : This device will play all the calls and conferencing, like Audio from Zoom, Teams and Meet

**"Default Device"** : This device plays all media, like videos, music, etc

For Microphone, or more generally any recording devices, It's just the same. :)

Comment: Thank You Wizard -  I am Learning as I go  (welcome to the 21st Century for me).  I have and will have Many questions as I educate myself.   One more question pertaining to audio settings is  one that I think is self explanatory but I will ask anyhow.  Audio vs Digital Jack when using the mic ?

Comment: @KevinH You mean *Analog vs Digital Jack*? I think it refers to whether your device is connected through the *Traditional* Audio jacks (that round circular ports) or like via USB. However I'm not very sure

Comment: - Got it - I didn't think about a USB .  Thank you again Wizard

Comment: I recently upgraded from windows 8.1 to 10 when purchasing a new laptop running Edge (which I am unfamiliar with) - I have the option to upgrade to windows 11 for Free -  what are the pros and cons when considering that ?

Comment: You're welcome @KevinH!, However, I would prefer you ask that as a separate question. Your previous Sub-Question seemed unfit for a separate Question and was still somehow related to the main question. However *this* def needs to be a different question. Answering questions like this isn't the *right* way here...

Comment: Understood...  My thanx once again